# add item inside Interactive Report Region

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to add text box at the top of the Inetractive Report Region or between action bar and the report itself. I tried to make IRR without heading but was not successful in that either. Any Help

Comment: The IRR report region does not provide any points where you can place items inside it, except for "Right of Interactive Report Search Bar". You may be able to make it work with some javascript.

Comment: As Jeffrey suggests, you could probably get something to work with a bit of JavaScript and CSS to re position the page items once the page has rendered. A bit hacky though.

Comment: Assuming that the id for the interactive report action bar is consistent, you may be able to append items in. For example `$('#apexir_TOOLBAR').append('<input>My textbox</input>');`. You could grab an item that you have created on the page elsewhere and append it in `$('#apexir_TOOLBAR').append($('#P100_MY_ITEM'));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dynamic action fired on page load and set it to execute the javascript code that I posted below:

```
document.getElementById('apexir_TOOLBAR').innerHTML = document.getElementById('apexir_TOOLBAR').innerHTML + '<label for="P5_X" class="uOptional"></label></td><td  align="left" valign="middle"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="11759631789729827" /><input type="text" id="P5_X" name="p_t01" class="text_field" style="margin:5px" value="" size="30" maxlength="4000"  />';
```

Or using the oracle-apex 'jquerysh' notation:

```
$x('apexir_TOOLBAR').innerHTML = $x('apexir_TOOLBAR').innerHTML + '<label for="P5_X" class="uOptional"></label></td><td  align="left" valign="middle"><input type="hidden" name="p_arg_names" value="11759631789729827" /><input type="text" id="P5_X" name="p_t01" class="text_field" style="margin:5px" value="" size="30" maxlength="4000"  />';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#P2_REPOSITION_CONTAINER").closest('.container').css({
    "left": "406px",
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": "0",
    "width": "659px",
    "z-index": "1"
});
```

Where `P2_REPOSITION` is the name of the field you want to be in toolbar.

If you have expand apex hides the field so you need also the following code in order to make it visible again. (`INT_REP` is the custom id of interactive report)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[aria-controls='INT_REP']").on('click', function(){
        $("#P2_REPOSITION_CONTAINER").closest('.container').show();
    });
});
```

I have added this code to `Function and Global Variable Declaration` of the page. But i think it would be no problem to add the javascript code in another region of the page.